# How to convert comma seperated string to a proper list inside a function to do further calculation

Tags: r, list, function

I have a tibble like this:

```
df <- tribble(
  ~prod_list, ~cust_list,
  "prod1,prod2", "cust1,cust2,cust3",
  "prod1,prod4,prod5","cust1,cust2,cust3,cust4,cust5,cust6"
)
```

I wanted to create a function to calculate the product/customer ratio (this ratio has no business meaning, just a simplification to show my problem. I do need to change the input variable to a list in my actual calculation).

```
calculate_ratio <-function (product_list, customer_list){
  list_prod <- as.list(str_split(product_list, ","))[[1]]
  list_cust <- as.list(str_split(customer_list, ","))[[1]]
  return(length(list_prod) / length(list_cust))
}
```

When I run

```
df %>% mutate(ratio = calculate_ratio(prod_list, cust_list))  


  prod_list         cust_list                               ratio
  <chr>             <chr>                                   <dbl>
1 prod1,prod2       cust1, cust2, cust3                     0.667
2 prod1,prod4,prod5 cust1, cust2, cust3,cust4, cust5, cust6 0.667
```

the ration for the second line should be **0.5**. Then it's clear that something wrong with the way I convert string to list. Any help would be highly appreciated:)

Answer (score 2):

By subsetting to `[[1]]`, you’re calculating the ratio for only the first row. Instead you want to iterate over each row. Using purrr:

```r
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
library(purrr)

calculate_ratio <- function (product_list, customer_list) {
  list_prod <- str_split(product_list, ",")
  list_cust <- str_split(customer_list, ",")
  map2_dbl(
    list_prod, 
    list_cust, 
    \(prod, cust) length(prod) / length(cust)
  )
}

df %>% 
  mutate(ratio = calculate_ratio(prod_list, cust_list))
```

Result:

```
# A tibble: 2 × 3
  prod_list         cust_list                           ratio
  <chr>             <chr>                               <dbl>
1 prod1,prod2       cust1,cust2,cust3                   0.667
2 prod1,prod4,prod5 cust1,cust2,cust3,cust4,cust5,cust6 0.5
```

PS - `str_split()` returns a list by default so no need to wrap in `as.list()`.

Comment: Thanks a lot. My original goal was to use these two lists as filter value to get a subset of a dataframe inside the function, something like this:    all_customers |> filter(product_id %in% list_prod & customer_id %in% list_cust) |> summarize(....).  when I ran the code I didn't get any error, but the result in summarize is the same for all rows. That made me thing something wrong with the way I pass those two lists into the filter. got to be something basic and fundamental I did wrong.

Comment: You can try changing `product_id %in% list_prod` to `str_detect(list_prod, str_c("\\b", product_id, "\\b"))` and likewise for `customer_id`.

Answer (score 2):

An alternative approach using `str_count`

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)

df %>% 
  mutate(ratio = (str_count(prod_list, ",") + 1) / (str_count(cust_list, ",") + 1))
# A tibble: 2 × 3
  prod_list         cust_list                           ratio
  <chr>             <chr>                               <dbl>
1 prod1,prod2       cust1,cust2,cust3                   0.667
2 prod1,prod4,prod5 cust1,cust2,cust3,cust4,cust5,cust6 0.5
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is how to adapt your code:

Slightly modify your function and apply it rowwise:

```
calculate_ratio <- function(product_list, customer_list) {
  vector_prod <- unlist(str_split(product_list, pattern = ","))
  vector_cust <- unlist(str_split(customer_list, pattern = ","))
  return(length(vector_prod) / length(vector_cust))
}

df %>% 
  rowwise() %>% 
  mutate(ratio = calculate_ratio(prod_list, cust_list))
```

```
  prod_list         cust_list                           ratio
  <chr>             <chr>                               <dbl>
1 prod1,prod2       cust1,cust2,cust3                   0.667
2 prod1,prod4,prod5 cust1,cust2,cust3,cust4,cust5,cust6 0.5
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Tar. You nailed my confusion. I read the document a bit. Is it the right understanding that by default, a function doesn't compute on a row at a time basis? but if I write a simple inline function, I don't have to use rowwise(). Appreciate if you could give me some hint.

Comment: This has nothing to do how functions work etc. It is simple a matter of your logic you want to apply:  
For the first row, the ratio should be 2/3 = 0.667
For the second row, the ratio should be 3/6 = 0.5. Therefore we need to calculate rowwise.